# hide and consider .php extension

Tags: .htaccess

Its old question I saw many answers in Stackoverflow but its not working for me.

I want to hide the php extension in my website which is hosted in godaddy. 
For the trail purpose I put all my files in www.example.com/temp/website

All the files php are stored in the folder "website" in the above link. And I save the .htaccess file in the same folder.

I tried the below code but its not working.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
```

Comment: It is unclear what you ask. Note that rewriting rules can never make a file name extension inside a link you sent out magically disappear. Rewriting rules only work on _incoming_ requests. So they enable the server to process requests without the extension in this case. Not more, not less.

Comment: Apart from that: "is not working" has never helped anyone at any time in any situation. What does that mean? Was there any error in the log file? Does the .htaccess file get considered at all? Was there no rewriting getting applied?  Did a rewriting occur, but wrong? Did the universe implode?

Comment: Dear, there is no error generated but when I enter www.example.com/temp/website/index.php its working but when I enter www.example.com/temp/website its not working. I want it to work when I put www.example.com/temp/website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should get you going. Note that I did not test this, but it should give you an idea:

```
RewriteEngine On

// rewrite requests without .php extension if the file exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.php$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/temp/website/%{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) /temp/website/$1.php [L]

// optional, as explained below: 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/temp/website/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule (.*) /temp/website/$1 [L]
```

1. test if the request does *not* have a `.php` extension
2. check if a file named like that *with an extension `.php`* exists in `/temp/website`
3. internally rewrite to that location and add the extension
4. you *might* want to add last lines to process incoming requests that *do* have the extension:

Answer (score 0):

Check if file doesn't exists (or images and css files and... will be redirected)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

then redirect to your folder and add the extension

```
RewriteRule (.*) /temp/website/$1\.php [L]
```